# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio Express - no server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having trouble with SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. There is no server name.

Earlier I installed the 2008 version but something wasn't right so I uninstalled and installed 2012. Upon installation 2nd time round there wasn't an instruction on instance to set to default. And there is no server name. local and "." don't work. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to windows services and make sure the sqlserver process is running.  Go to the SQL Server configuration manager and make sure in the protocols TCP/IP is enabled.  Also the default instance name for express is   .\sqlexpress   have you tried connecting with that name